# React Bootstrap Alert Default true

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-alert-bqongx
How to do react bootstrap alert with out "Show alert button"? need the alert box visible by default page load.

```
function Alerts(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  if (show) {
    return (
      <Alert variant="danger" onClose={() => setShow(false)} dismissible>
        <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo</p>
      </Alert>
    );
  }
 //with out this return <Button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Show Alert</Button>;
}

export default Alerts;
```

Comment: what do you mean with "visible by default page load"? In your code sandbox the alert is shown by default. Isn't this what you try to achieve?

Comment: without this button <Button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Show Alert</Button>; .

if I click on X close button then alert will be hidden & this button will be visible to click and get the alert box again. I just wanted the alert box on page load only.
once I click X then alert will be hidden, again alert should visible only if I reload.refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Button component and use "show" and "onClose" properties of Alert to manage the state/visibility:

```
<Alert
    variant="danger"
    show={show}
    dismissible
    onClose={() => setShow(false)}
>
```

I have corrected and simplified your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-alert-forked-g0fjcg

Edit: When dealing with multiple objects, use following pattern:

- Create a state object or array, which can manage the state of every object. Take id as property key and it's state as value.
- Create a callback, which will set the appropriate state.
- When iterating over the objects for the UI, set the state and callback.

In your case state could look like:

```
{
    alert1: true,
    alert2: true,
    alert3: true
}
```

Callback function:

```
const hideAlert = (id) =>
    setShow((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [id]: false };
    });
```

Setting state and callback for UI:

```
<Alert
    variant="danger"
    show={show[alert.id]}
    dismissible
    onClose={() => hideAlert(alert.id)}
>
```

I have updated the sandbox.

Comment: its working but if we use multiple <alert>  then the X close button of any alert is closing all alert boxs together